# I am trying to keep the objects of csv files into a linked list to search for the tshirts But I am getting cannot infer type arguments for linked list

Tags: java, maven

My program is to implement a standalone product search program in Java that lists matching
products for a user who is looking for T-shirts. I am given 3 CSV files. I am trying to keep
the objects of CSV files into a `LinkedList` to search for the T-shirts but I am getting *cannot
infer type arguments* for `LinkedList`.
Here is my code in which I am trying to store objects of CSV file into `LinkedList`.

```java
package com.example.Mavenassignmentone;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FindTshirt {
    List<ShirtModel> shirtlist = new LinkedList<ShirtModel>();
    LinkedList<String> list;
    showTshirt sh = new showTshirt();

    public void find(String filename, String COLOUR, String GENDER_RECOMMENDATION, String SIZE)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String sentence = sc.nextLine().toString();
            if (!sentence.isEmpty()) {
                StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(sentence, "|");
                list = new LinkedList<>(sentence.length());
                while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    list.add(token.nextToken());
                }
                if (list.get(1).equals(COLOUR) && list.get(2).equals(GENDER_RECOMMENDATION)
                        && list.get(3).equals(SIZE)) {
                    ShirtModel model = new ShirtModel(list.get(0), list.get(1), list.get(2),
                            list.get(3), list.get(4), Integer.parseInt(list.get(5)),
                            Float.parseFloat(list.get(6)), list.get(7));
                    shirtlist.add(model);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateView(int choiceCode) {
        if (choiceCode == 1) {
            Collections.sort(shirtlist, new Comparator<ShirtModel>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(ShirtModel o1, ShirtModel o2) {
                    return o1.getPrice() - o2.getPrice();
                }
            });
        }
        else if (choiceCode == 2) {
            Collections.sort(shirtlist, new Comparator<ShirtModel>() {
                public int compare(ShirtModel o1, ShirtModel o2) {
                    return (int) (o1.getRating() - o2.getRating());
                }
            });
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong Choice.");
            return;
        }
        sh.viewtshirt(shirtlist);
    }
}
```

This line of code is giving error:

```java
list=new LinkedList<>(sentence.length());
```

Error is

> cannot infer type arguments

Comment: the error is coming it is  undefined .

Comment: no , I have done that I just needed to find the length of the object i am storing in linked list . , for sentence.length its coming int type is undefined  .. by the way , problem is solved , I was making a slight mistake and was stuck since 2 days ..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line of your code.

```java
list = new LinkedList<>(sentence.length());
```

There is no constructor of class [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) that takes an `int` parameter.
The line should be:

```java
list = new LinkedList<>();
```

For the sake of completeness, here is your code with the correction. There is one change and it is marked with the comment `CHANGE HERE`.

```java
package com.example.Mavenassignmentone;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FindTshirt {
    List<ShirtModel> shirtlist = new LinkedList<ShirtModel>();
    LinkedList<String> list;
    showTshirt sh = new showTshirt();

    public void find(String filename, String COLOUR, String GENDER_RECOMMENDATION, String SIZE)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String sentence = sc.nextLine().toString();
            if (!sentence.isEmpty()) {
                StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(sentence, "|");
                list = new LinkedList<>(); // CHANGE HERE
                while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    list.add(token.nextToken());
                }
                if (list.get(1).equals(COLOUR) && list.get(2).equals(GENDER_RECOMMENDATION)
                        && list.get(3).equals(SIZE)) {
                    ShirtModel model = new ShirtModel(list.get(0), list.get(1), list.get(2),
                            list.get(3), list.get(4), Integer.parseInt(list.get(5)),
                            Float.parseFloat(list.get(6)), list.get(7));
                    shirtlist.add(model);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateView(int choiceCode) {
        if (choiceCode == 1) {
            Collections.sort(shirtlist, new Comparator<ShirtModel>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(ShirtModel o1, ShirtModel o2) {
                    return o1.getPrice() - o2.getPrice();
                }
            });
        }
        else if (choiceCode == 2) {
            Collections.sort(shirtlist, new Comparator<ShirtModel>() {
                public int compare(ShirtModel o1, ShirtModel o2) {
                    return (int) (o1.getRating() - o2.getRating());
                }
            });
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong Choice.");
            return;
        }
        sh.viewtshirt(shirtlist);
    }
}
```

Note that this solves the compiler error you are getting however I did not check whether the code executes correctly since you did not post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because your code is missing classes `ShirtModel` and `showTshirt`.

Answer (score 0):

The `list` is declared as a `LinkedList` of `String` via `LinkedList<String>list;`, but `list` is initialized as a new linked list with an `int` as the constructor argument, but the [`LinkedList` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList(java.util.Collection)) that you are using accepts a *collection* as its constructor, not an `int`.

This is the reason the compiler cannot infer the type arguments. From the [Java type inference doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#:%7E:text=Type%20inference%20is%20a%20Java,that%20make%20the%20invocation%20applicable.&text=Finally%2C%20the%20inference%20algorithm%20tries,with%20all%20of%20the%20arguments.):

> The inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if available, the type that the result is being assigned, or returned. Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the *most specific* type that works with all of the arguments.

The easiest fix would be to initialize the `list` with the empty `LinkedList` constructor:

```java
list = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to identify the type of the linked list, change the line to

```
list=new LinkedList<String>();
```

and moreover, you in linkedList, you don't have to identify the length.